# Unexpected termination of my Java program

Tags: java, hashmap

As soon as the buffered reader takes the testcase value and creates a hashmap, the program terminates. It does not enter the loop. Can anyone explain why ?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.*;

class anagram {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
int testcases = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
HashMap <String, Integer> mymap = new HashMap < String, Integer >();
for(int entry = 97; entry < 123; entry++){  
    String ekey = String.valueOf((char)entry);
    mymap.put(ekey , 0);
}

for( int loop1 = 1; loop1 == testcases; loop1++){

    String a = br.readLine();
    String b = br.readLine();

    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(b);


}   
}
}
```

Comment: `loop1 <= testcases`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `for` loop is wrong. It will only ever loop once and only if testCases is 1.

Try this instead:

```
for( int loop1 = 0; loop1 < testCases; ++loop1 )
```

FYI - There is nothing wrong with starting at `1` and going until `<= numIterations`, however general programming convention is to start at value `0` and go till `< numIterations` because that is how arrays work (1st element is at index `0`, then 10th is at index `9`).

Comment: That happens all the time to the best of us, especially if you've been staring at the same code all day. Your eye glosses over what is actually there and your brain see what you had intended to put there. ;)

Comment: Yes I know. I generally start it at 0 only. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

use `for( int loop1 = 1; loop1 <= testcases; loop1++)`

What I meant was to use '<=' instead of '=='